# How do I add join conditions on many to many relationships in SQL Alchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy, relational-database

I have the models `A` and `B`, connected in a many-to-many relationship using the `secondary` parameter referring to the model `AB` (the association table).

Using `query(A).options(joinedload(A.b))` will generate the query:

```
SELECT ...
FROM a
LEFT OUTER JOIN (a_b AS a_b_1 JOIN b ON b.id = a_b_1.b_id) ON a.id = a_b_1.a_id
```

But I want extra conditions on the join (not using WHERE!), in order to filter on a certain flag in `B`. So just like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM a
LEFT OUTER JOIN (a_b AS a_b_1 JOIN b ON b.id = a_b_1.b_id AND b.flag = 1) ON a.id = a_b_1.a_id
```

How do I do that using SQL Alchemy?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [and_()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.and_) expression with *.outerjoin()*. Just an example with 2 models:

```
from sqlalchemy import and_

class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'a'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'b'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    a_id = Column(Integer)
    flag = Column(String)


a = A()
session.add(a)
session.commit()

# just a few records. without flag + with flag
b1 = B(a_id=a.id)
b2 = B(a_id=a.id, flag='Cs_Is_Better')

session.add(b1)
session.add(b2)
session.commit()

query = session.query(A).outerjoin(B, (and_(A.id == B.a_id, B.flag == 'Cs_Is_Better')))

print(query)
# SELECT a.id AS a_id 
# FROM a LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id AND b.flag = %(flag_1)s
print(query.all())  # [<__main__.A object at 0x112fb4780>]
```

So just add any conditions to `outerjoin`:

```
.outerjoin(ModelName, (and_(...))
```

Hope this helps.